# Url.Link() not generating proper link with querystring

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm creating an ASP.NET Core WebAPI that has a route with an optional parameter.  In the return result I am embedding links to "previous" and "next" pages. I'm using `Url.Link()` to generate these links, but the link created is not generating a proper URL.

Example code:

```
  [HttpGet("{page:int?}", Name = "GetResultsRoute")]
  public IActionResult GetResults([FromQuery]int page = 0)
  {
     ...
     var prevUrl = Url.Link("GetResultsRoute", new { page = page - 1 });
     var nextUrl = Url.Link("GetResultsRoute", new { page = page + 1 });
     ...
```

The URL generated will be something like:

```
http://localhost:65061/api/results/1
```

What I want is:

```
http://localhost:65061/api/results?page=1
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are doing everything right here. It just MVC is able to match your [page] value in Url.Link to the route constraint HttpGet("{page:int?}", thus appending it as a part of the URL path, e.g. results/1
From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing) - Ambient values that don't match a parameter are ignored, and ambient values are also ignored when an explicitly-provided value overrides it, going from left to right in the URL. **Values that are explicitly provided but which don't match anything are added to the query string.**
In your case,

```
var prevUrl = Url.Link("GetResultsRoute", new { pageX = page - 1 });
```

would result in

```
http://localhost:65061/api/results?pageX=1
```

So ether append the query string parameter yourself, remove the constraint, or switch to MVC recommend format of URL, e.g. `/api/results/xxx`.

Comment: That's it, I need to drop the page has a route constraint.  [HttpGet(Name = "GetResultsRoute")]
      public IActionResult GetResults([FromQuery]int page = 0) causes the link to generate correctly.